# Ibeacons proximity incorrect

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon, estimote

I have been using estimote beacons to work with near and immediate proximities. But Im noticing some weird behavior from the beacons. The beacons that are about 30 m far are also being detected as near and immediate. Im not sure if this has something to do with the broadcasting power and advertising interval settings. If it is can some one please tell me the optimal settings for them. The reason I think this could be the cause is because the beacons were show good proximity readings before the latest os update.

Thank you

Comment: do you mean that they are immediate and near at the same time or some of them are near and some immediate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Wojtek Borowicz, I'm a community evangelist at Estimote.

Adjusting advertising interval and broadcasting power should help. Generally, the lower the interval and the higher the broadcasting power, the more stable and reliable the signal (keep in mind it affects battery life as well!). Also, note that strong wireless interference might impact the signal readings too.

Cheers.